# When data is changed, doesn't update on UI but seen in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

In a React project, with certain records of input fields, date data can be changed, but, doesn't reflect it on UI and when seen in console, its shown over there. I'm using react datepicker for date component. Please refer to code below:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState();

{colConfig[cIndex].data_type === "date" &&
   !colConfig[cIndex].cell_click_callback && (
   <div>
   <DatePickerNew
   setRequesterDate={(e) =>
   dateCallback({dateVal: e, id: rowData[0].id})}
      startDate={colData}
      setStartDate={setStartDate}
      />
   </div>
)}
```

As you can see from above code, I'm passing 'coldata' from props and accordingly displaying. The data doesn't get updated on UI but, its seen in console.

You can see from image below, the date data is changed for 'Shawns' but it isn't updated on UI, but, can be seen in console. What could be the best solution to sort it out?

[image]

Please refer to codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-varahamihira-xpjtdb?file=/src/Grid.js:499-544

Comment: startDate={colData} should be replaced with  startDate={startDate}

Comment: I did that, but, want to make changes with colData only... I mean change the colData's date.

Comment: Your implementation is very wrong. You have made it complex unnecessarily. Also  you are using colData which is comes from rowData which is an Array and it contains data other than dates.

Comment: It will take date data only and display in the grid... We need to take that colData value and make changes... Please refer codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you set your `startDate` properly but never use it to display the data.

If you just use `startDate` in you component instead of `colData`, you will see the changes starting to reflect properly:

```
 <DatePickerNew
   setRequesterDate={(e) =>
     dateCallback({dateVal: e, id: rowData[0].id})
   }
   startDate={startDate} // <- Using startDate here
   setStartDate={setStartDate}
 />
```

You would obviously need state for each row seperately which would be much better if you have the `startDate` state inside the `DatePickerNew` component

Comment: Yes... I know... but I want to make changes to colData... I mean set that new changed data